# How can I make not-encoded cookies in Sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby, cookies, sinatra, encode

I'm developing a website with Sinatra, a Ruby framework, and I have a cookie that gets a number from the database, this way:

`cookies[:id] = database.execute "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username=?", params[:username]`

The database returns a value like this: `[1]`, which is automatically encoded as `%5B1%5D`. According to what I've read, it is an URL encoding and it's possible to decode it with CGI. But is there any way to create a cookie without such encoding? I need a human readable one.

Comment: Just a guess, but browser cookies are simple key-value pairs of strings and your database query might be returning an array. Try explicitly converting your query result to a string of the desired format first.

Comment: When I print the database value in the console, with `puts` and using another variable, it shows like this: `1`. But I'm gonna do what you said.

Comment: Indeed, it is in the shape of an array, and when converted into string it receives the `[]`.

Comment: I solved the problem this way: `temp = database.execute "SELECT Id FROM Users WHERE Username=?", params[:username]`, `temp = temp[0][0].to_s`, `cookies[:id] = temp`.